# Is there a way to get the crashlog sent to Apple by customer?

Tags: macos, crash-reports, crash-log

When a Mac OS application crash you get this well known popup:
[image]

What happens exactly when the user clicks on the *Report...* button?

Is there a way to have access to the generated crashlog?

Is there anything like Microsoft [WER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513641(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks on the report button, it displays more information about what caused the crash, including a stack trace and the registers of all the threads used by the application.

You can view these in the OSX [Console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_%28OS_X%29) application under the title "Diagnostics and Usage Information".

I don't believe Apple currently provide a system for 3rd party developers, like WER.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am already aware about CrashReport content thanks to [Apple TN2123](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html).